# Bootstrap 3 left close bar 100% height with container-fluid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a layout for a page like this with a full height left close bar. I keep running into the left close bar either pushing everything down or is limited to only the top left corner:

[image]

Comment: so what is your problem can you explain more please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make the sidebar full height you can use

```
.sidebar{
   height:100vh;
}
```

and then you can give `position:fixed;`

Comment: This works for full height close button but now the center overlays the button.

Comment: you should provide me some html and css code please

Comment: Sorry the last error was on my end. Just needed to position the div outside of the container. Thanks! I'll accept your answer when stack overflow's time delay runs out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like that.

```css
body {margin:0;}
.side {
  position: fixed;
  background: blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
.content {
  padding-left: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.top {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  float: left;
}
.left, .right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.left {
  background: green;
}
.right {
  background: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div class="side"></div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```